# Return multiple user in Django

Tags: python, django

My tests are failing saying  get() returned more than one permissions -- it returned 2!
However I want to return more than one permission, but I could not get the list. I'm using ajax to display those list on modal. My problem is I want to display all usertype name base on idd below. If any expert could help please share some solution thanks in advance.

```
returned more than one permissions -- it returned 2!
```

[Permissiontable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUzHl.jpg)
[usertypetable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cul0M.jpg)

> views.py

```
def ajax(request):
  idd = request.GET.get('id')

  app_permission_tbl_usid = permissions.objects.get(user_id=idd)
  app_permission_tbl_permid = app_permission_tbl_usid.permission_id
  datas = usertypes.objects.get(id=app_permission_tbl_permid)


  list_of_permission = datas.usertype
  return JsonResponse({"result": list_of_permission})
```

> models.py

```
class AuthUser(models.Model):
  password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
  last_login = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
  is_superuser = models.IntegerField()
  username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150)
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
  email = models.CharField(max_length=254)
  is_staff = models.IntegerField()
  is_active = models.IntegerField()
  date_joined = models.DateTimeField()

  class Meta:
     managed = False
     db_table = 'auth_user'

class usertypes(models.Model):
  usertype = models.CharField(max_length=264)
  description = models.CharField(max_length=264)
  status = models.CharField(max_length=264)

class permissions(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, models.DO_NOTHING)
  permission = models.ForeignKey(usertypes, models.DO_NOTHING)
```

> javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function modal (post_id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/',
        data: {
            'id': post_id
        },
        success: function(response){
            document.getElementById('firstNameValueId').innerHTML = response.result
            $("#editmodal").modal('show');
        }
    });
}
```

> my modal display result

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="firstNameValueId" size="10" class="duallistbox">
<option value="1">Admin</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You should use `.filter` instead of `.get`. This will also mean that you can not use `.permission_id`, since there are multiple.

Comment: Can you share the relevant models?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thank you for your response , I've updated and added models above. please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `.filter` instead of `.get`. This will also mean that you can not use `.permission_id`, since there are multiple.

You can make use of a query that JOINs on the `permissions` model, and thus filters with:

```
def ajax(request):
    datas = list(usertypes.objects.filter(
        permissions__user_id=request.GET['id']
    ).values_list('usertype', flat=True))
    return JsonResponse({'result': datas})
```

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PerlCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`Permission`</s> to `permissions`.

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `UserType` instead of <s>`UserTypes`</s>.

If you rename the models accordingly, the query should be rewritten to:

```
def ajax(request):
    datas = list(UserType.objects.filter(
        permission__user_id=request.GET['id']
    ).values_list('usertype', flat=True))
    return JsonResponse({'result': datas})
```

Comment: I appreciate your quick response but I'm getting error  'usertypes' object has no attribute 'values_list' . is values_list a default?

Comment: this is the table looks like ,https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUzHl.jpg  just want to retrieve list of usertype name through getting the idd and this my usertypes https://i.stack.imgur.com/cul0M.jpg , I appreciate your response thanks

Comment: @D-jason: sorry, I made a typo, it is `.filter`, not `.get`

Comment: It works! I owe you thank you. I have one more question do you have idea on how can I display those usertype name in option? I added my ajax above, I think this is the fastiest way to ask to meet my  defense tomorrow  please help thank you!

Comment: do you prefer to use loop? to separate every value of list?